# Find $\alpha$ and it's quadrant knowing that $\cos(\pi - \alpha)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin \alpha < 0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$\cos(\pi - \alpha)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin \alpha < 0$

I tried:

$$\cos(\pi-\alpha) = \frac{1}{2} \\ \Leftrightarrow \pi - \alpha = \arccos(\frac{1}{2})+2k\pi \lor \pi - \alpha = - \arccos(\frac{1}{2})+2k\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
-\alpha = \arccos(\frac{1}{2})+2k\pi - \pi \lor -\alpha = -\arccos(\frac{1}{2})+2k\pi -\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
-\alpha = \frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi-\pi \lor -\alpha = -\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi-\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
-\alpha = \frac{\pi + 6k\pi-3\pi}{3} \lor -\alpha = \frac{-\pi+6k\pi-3\pi}{3} \Leftrightarrow \\
\alpha = -\pi(\frac{1+6k-3}{3})\lor \alpha = -\pi(\frac{-1+6k-3}{3}) \Leftrightarrow \\
\alpha = -2\pi(\frac{3k-2}{3}) \lor \alpha = -2\pi(\frac{3k-2}{3})$$

Then I tried solving for $\sin \alpha < 0$:

$$\sin \alpha < 0 \Leftrightarrow \alpha < \arcsin(0)+2k\pi \lor \alpha > \pi - \arcsin(0)+2k\pi \Leftrightarrow \\
\alpha <2k\pi \lor \alpha > \pi-2k\pi$$

Are the < and > signs correct above? How do I know where they are supposed to turn to in this case?

And what do I do next? How do I solve this?

Comment: First consider the four quadrants, trial and error, then add in the $2k\pi$.  Tad bit simpler in my opinion.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I agree, but I think I am supposed to solve this analitically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to memorize the main reduction formulas:

$$\cos\,(180-α)=-\cosα $$
$$\sin\,(180-α)=\sinα $$
$$\cos\,(90-α)=\sinα $$
$$\sin\,(90-α)=\cosα $$
Periods are
$$\cos\,(α±360)=\cosα $$
$$\sin\,(α±360)=\sinα $$
And also these ones (odd and even properties):
$$\cos\,(-α)=\cosα $$
$$\sin\,(-α)=-\sinα $$

**These are all a must as is the sound knowledge of their graphs. There's no trigonometry without basics**

You also need to know basic angles and things like  sine being negative from $180$ to $360$. And your answer is exactly in that range. Yet 300 degrees doesn't fit cos cosine is positive there. You got a negative cosine:

$\quad\cos\,(180-α)=-\cosα =0.5\quad$ or  $\quad\cosα =-0.5\quad$

**Means the angle is $240$ degrees or $4π/3$  since $300$ degrees ($5π/3$) is positive for the cosine**. So $300$ degrees doesn't fit. Angles less than $180$ degrees don't fit either, as the sine is negative (from $180$ to $360$)

And one more piece of advice. Sometimes it is better to visualize sine/cosine graphs rather than struggle through quadrants so that there's less confusion.

No calculations are needed in your problem in my opinion. Just common sense. If you can get instantaneous answers (in your mind) about all degrees and pi parts withing the range 0-360 for the sine and cosine, you've mastered the basics. That's much easier than it seems. Sometimes textbooks are as clear as mud confusing students a lot. I see it a lot. It's incredible why it is this way. Even I'm confused.

Hope it was helpful

Comment: That's very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha=\frac 12\implies \alpha=\pm\frac{2\pi}{3}+n\cdot2\pi$

Then $\sin\alpha<0\implies \alpha=-\frac{2\pi}{3}$ in the third quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

Using basic trigonometric identities:

$$\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha>0\implies \cos\alpha<0\implies \text{we're in 2nd or 3rd quadrant}$$

but if also $\;\sin\alpha<0\;$ then we **must** be in the third one.

And now simply $\;\cos\alpha=\frac12\implies\alpha=\frac\pi3+k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , and in the third quadrant this means $\;\alpha=\frac{4\pi}3=\frac\pi3+\pi\;$